# regex for searching in visual studio: does not end with true, true);

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I need to find all `Response.Redirect();`'s which do not end with `true, true);`
I think using a Regex with Search in Visual Studio is the best option to find those, but i have no idea on how to make that regex. in the `response.redirect` can be anything, but it can't end on `true, true);`
Those are the ones I want to find.

Any idea on the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
Response\.Redirect\s*\(.*?(?<!true\s*\,\s*true\s*)\);
```

Search for "Response.Redirect",
- followed by 0 or more white spaces
- followed by a (
- followed by the shortest sequence of any chars
- that doesn't terminate by true, true );

Comment: I don't think that VS search supports lookarounds. (But it should ...)

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but when I use this, it finds no results. (even though there are)

Comment: PS: you dont have to mind about the spaces. it's always formatted, so it's true, true); you're (not) looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
true, true\);$
```

explanation:

- ) is special character, so you need to escape it.
- $ at the end will match string ends with regex.

---

To match X and not match Y, then try:

```
$regex1 = '/^Response\.Redirect\(/';
$regex2 = '/true, true\);$/';
```

Then:

```
if (preg_match($regex1, $s) && !preg_match($regex2, $s)) { // match } else { // not match }
```

Examples:

```
$s = 'Response.Redirect("something", true, true);'; // false
$s = 'Response.Redirect("something");'; // true
$s = '("something", true, true);'; // false
```

Sorry the sample in PHP. But you can adapt the regex & logic.

Comment: it has to start with Response.Redirect

Comment: That will find those the OP don't want to find!

Comment: @stema Sorry, i read the question wrong. I has edited the answer. Hope it helps :-)

Comment: i'm using this regex as a search query, it has to be in 1 regex.